# Giving two different positions for 2 different images in same class

Tags: css

Is there any way to give 2 images different positions in the same class?

```
<div class="image">
 <img src="image1.jpg">
 <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image img {
 top: 100px;
}
```

Is it possible to give image1 a different position value than image2 in the same class?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you select the first image using `.image img:first-child` and you set a different top value - something like `.image img:first-child { top: 50px; }`